# Reading the words of a file into a dynamic 2D array

Tags: c, parsing, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read a file and store every word into a dynamically allocated 2D array. The size of the input file is unknown.

I am totally lost and don't know how I could "fix/finish" the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char filename[25];
    printf("Input the filename");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    fileConverter(filename);
}

int fileConverter(char filename[25]) {
    //int maxLines = 50000;
    //int maxWordSize = 128;
    //char words[maxLines][maxWordSize];
    //char **words;
    char **arr = (char**) calloc(num_elements, sizeof(char*));

    for ( i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ ) {
        arr[i] = (char*) calloc(num_elements_sub, sizeof(char));
    }
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int amountOfWords = 0;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }
    while(fgets(words[amountOfWords], 10000, file)) {
        words[amountOfWords][strlen(words[amountOfWords]) - 1] = "\0";
        amountOfWords++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfWords; i++) {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
    printf("The file contains %d words and the same amount of lines.\n", amountOfWords);

    return amountOfWords;
```

Comment: it is not 2D array only array of pointers

Comment: `words[amountOfWords][strlen(words[amountOfWords]) - 1] = "\0";` will not work. The string literal You should just assign `0` (no quotes, single or double). It is also highly presumptive concerning the last line may *not* end with a newline. As-written it won't even *compile* since `words` isn't even declared (it's commented out). And `fgets` is more tuned for reading *lines*, not words (unless you already know each line contains *only* one word; again, presumptive).

Comment: What is 'num_elements'? reallocarray  (reallocarray() is a nonstandard extension)  : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html

Comment: Do you really need to *store* the words, or just *count* the words? `system("wc <input>")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main challenges for this kind of problem are

- reallocating the array of strings as the program reads new words, and
- handling words that are larger than the buffer used by `fgets`.

The general approach for these kind of parsing problems, is to design a *state machine*. The state machine here has two states:

1. The current character is **whitespace**. Action: Continue reading whitespace until we reach the end of the buffer, or until we land on a non-whitespace character, in which case we switch to state 2.
2. The current character is **non-whitespace** (i.e. a word). Action: Continue reading non-whitespace until we reach the end of the buffer, or until we land on a whitespace character, in which case we copy the word we just read to the array of strings and switch to state 1.

Particularly difficult is the case in which we are in state 2 and reach the end of the buffer. This means that this word spans multiple buffers. To accommodate for this, we deviate slightly from a direct state machine implementation. State 2 is slightly different, depending on if we are reading a new word or continuing one that was started in a previous buffer.
We now keep track of `wordSize`. If we start reading from the start of a buffer, but `wordSize` is not 0, then we know we are continuing a previous word *and* we know what size it was for the `realloc` we need.

Below is one possible implementation. All the work is done in the `wordArrayRead` function. Walking through it from the top of the function:

First we declare the variables that we need across `lineBuffer` reads: an index for the word itself and the length of the word we are currently reading, followed by the declaration of the buffer itself. The outside loop repeatedly reads using `fgets` until we have exhausted the input.
We start reading at index 0 and stop at the null-terminator. The first if-statement checks if we should be in state 2: either the current character is the start of a word or we were already reading a word.

**State 2**
The index `wordStartIdx` stays at the first character of the word (segment) and we walk the `wordEndIdx` to the end of the word (segment) or to the end of the buffer.
We then check if we need to increase the size of the array of strings. Here we increase it to 2 times + 1 the previous size to avoid frequent reallocations.
We set a boolean value, indication whether we have reached the end of a word. If we have, we need to allocate for and write the null-terminator at the end of the string.
If `wordLength == 0` it means we are reading a new word and have to allocate memory for it for the first time. If `wordLength != 0`, we have to reallocate to append to an existing word.
We copy the word (segment) currently in the `lineBuffer` to the array of strings.
Now, we do some bookkeeping. If we reached the end of a word, we write the null-terminator, increment the index to point to the next word location and reset `wordLength`. If this wasn't the case, we only increment the `wordLength` with the length of the segment we just read. Finally, we update `wordStartIdx`, which still points to the start of the word, to point to the end of the word, so we can continue iterating over the buffer.

**State 1**
Having finishing the State 2 processing, we go into State 1 which has only two lines. It simply advances the index until we land at non-whitespace. Note that the null-terminator of the `lineBuffer` (`'\0'`) does *not* count as whitespace, so this loop will not continue past the end of the buffer.

After all input has been processed, we shrink the array of strings to the actual size of its data. This "corrects" the allocation policy of increasing the size by 2n+1 each time it wasn't large enough.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// BUFFER_SIZE must be >1U
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024U

struct WordArray
{
    char **words;
    size_t numberOfWords;
};

static struct WordArray wordArrayConstruct(void);
static void wordArrayResize(struct WordArray *wordArray, size_t const newSize);
static void wordArrayDestruct(struct WordArray *wordArray);
static void wordArrayRead(FILE *restrict stream, struct WordArray *wordArray);
static char *reallocStringWrapper(char *restrict str, size_t const newSize);
static void wordArrayPrint(struct WordArray const *wordArray);

int main(void)
{
    struct WordArray wordArray = wordArrayConstruct();
    wordArrayRead(stdin, &wordArray);
    wordArrayPrint(&wordArray);
    wordArrayDestruct(&wordArray);
}

static void wordArrayRead(FILE *restrict stream, struct WordArray *wordArray)
{
    size_t wordArrayIdx = 0U;
    size_t wordLength = 0U;

    char lineBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof lineBuffer, stream) != NULL)
    {
        size_t wordStartIdx = 0U;
        while (lineBuffer[wordStartIdx] != '\0')
        {
            if (!isspace(lineBuffer[wordStartIdx]) || wordLength != 0U)
            {
                size_t wordEndIdx = wordStartIdx;
                while (!isspace(lineBuffer[wordEndIdx]) && wordEndIdx != BUFFER_SIZE - 1U)
                    ++wordEndIdx;

                if (wordArrayIdx >= wordArray->numberOfWords)
                    wordArrayResize(wordArray, wordArray->numberOfWords * 2U + 1U);

                size_t wordSegmentLength = wordEndIdx - wordStartIdx;
                size_t foundWordEnd = wordEndIdx != BUFFER_SIZE - 1U; // 0 or 1 bool

                // Allocate for a new word, or reallocate for an existing word
                // If a word end was found, add 1 to the size for the '\0' character
                char *dest = wordLength == 0U ? NULL : wordArray->words[wordArrayIdx];
                size_t allocSize = wordLength + wordSegmentLength + foundWordEnd;
                wordArray->words[wordArrayIdx] = reallocStringWrapper(dest, allocSize);

                memcpy(&(wordArray->words[wordArrayIdx][wordLength]),
                       &lineBuffer[wordStartIdx], wordSegmentLength);

                if (foundWordEnd)
                {
                    wordArray->words[wordArrayIdx][wordLength + wordSegmentLength] = '\0';
                    ++wordArrayIdx;
                    wordLength = 0U;
                }
                else
                {
                    wordLength += wordSegmentLength;
                }
                wordStartIdx = wordEndIdx;
            }

            while (isspace(lineBuffer[wordStartIdx]))
                ++wordStartIdx;
        }
    }

    // All done. Shrink the words array to the size of the actual data
    if (wordArray->numberOfWords != 0U)
        wordArrayResize(wordArray, wordArrayIdx);
}

static struct WordArray wordArrayConstruct(void)
{
    return (struct WordArray) {.words = NULL, .numberOfWords = 0U};
}

static void wordArrayResize(struct WordArray *wordArray, size_t const newSize)
{
    assert(newSize > 0U);
    char **tmp = (char**) realloc(wordArray->words, newSize * sizeof *wordArray->words);

    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        wordArrayDestruct(wordArray);
        fprintf(stderr, "WordArray allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    wordArray->words = tmp;
    wordArray->numberOfWords = newSize;
}

static void wordArrayDestruct(struct WordArray *wordArray)
{
    for (size_t wordStartIdx = 0U; wordStartIdx < wordArray->numberOfWords; ++wordStartIdx)
    {
        free(wordArray->words[wordStartIdx]);
        wordArray->words[wordStartIdx] = NULL;
    }

    free(wordArray->words);
}

static char *reallocStringWrapper(char *restrict str, size_t const newSize)
{
    char *tmp = (char*) realloc(str, newSize);

    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        free(str);
        fprintf(stderr, "Realloc string allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}

static void wordArrayPrint(struct WordArray const *wordArray)
{
    for (size_t wordStartIdx = 0U; wordStartIdx < wordArray->numberOfWords; ++wordStartIdx)
        printf("%zu: %s\n", wordStartIdx, wordArray->words[wordStartIdx]);
}
```

Note: This program reads input from `stdin`, as Unix/Linux utilities typically do. Use input redirection to read from a file, or provide a file descriptor to the `readWordArray` function.

Answer (score -2):

to allocate dynamic 2D array you need:

```
void allocChar2Darray(size_t rows, size_t columns, char (**array)[columns])
{
    *array = malloc(rows * sizeof(**array));
}
```